# PeriodFormatter For ZoneDateTime

Tags: java, jodatime, zoneddatetime

PeriodFormatter is in package org.joda.time.And it used for LocalDateTime.But what is want a PeriodFormatter for Zonedatetime.Here is code below

```
  Period period = new Period(localtime1, localtime2, PeriodType.standard());

    PeriodFormatter dhm = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
            .printZeroNever()
            .appendYears()
            .appendSuffix(" " + pickUpYear + " ", " " + pickUpYears + " ")
            .appendSeparator(" " + pickUpTimeSeparator + " ")
            .printZeroNever()
            .appendMonths()
            .appendSuffix(" " + pickUpMonth + " ", " " + pickUpMonths + " ")
            .appendSeparator(" " + pickUpTimeSeparator + " ")
            .printZeroNever()
            .appendDays()
            .appendSuffix(" " + pickUpDay + " ", " " + pickUpDays + " ")
            .appendSeparator(" " + pickUpTimeSeparator + " ")
            .printZeroNever()
            .appendHours()
            .appendSuffix(" " + pickUpHour + " ", " " + pickUpHours + " ")
            .appendSeparator(" " + pickUpTimeSeparator + " ")
            .printZeroNever()
            .appendMinutes()
            .appendSuffix(" " + pickUpMinute + " ", " " + pickUpMinutes + " ")
            .toFormatter();

    return dhm.print(period.normalizedStandard());
```

localtime1 and localtime2 is LocalDateTime object.But i want to use ZoneDateTime instead of that. What is the alternate for ZoneDateTime?

Answer (score 2):

The Joda-Time equivalent of java.time’s `ZonedDateTime` is simply called `DateTime`. So just use it.

```
    DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Thimphu");
    DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(2021, 6, 19, 10, 0, zone);
    DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(2022, 6, 21, 14, 0, zone);
    
    Period period = new Period(dt1, dt2, PeriodType.standard());

    PeriodFormatter dhm = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
            .printZeroNever()
            .appendYears()
            .appendSuffix(" y ", " ys ")
            .appendSeparator(" , ")
            .printZeroNever()
            .appendMonths()
            .appendSuffix(" m ", " ms ")
            .appendSeparator(" , ")
            .printZeroNever()
            .appendDays()
            .appendSuffix(" d ", " ds ")
            .appendSeparator(" ; ")
            .printZeroNever()
            .appendHours()
            .appendSuffix(" h ", " hs ")
            .appendSeparator(" : ")
            .printZeroNever()
            .appendMinutes()
            .appendSuffix(" m ", " ms ")
            .toFormatter();
    
    String result = period.toString(dhm);
    
    System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

> 1 y  , 2 ds  ; 4 hs

Comment: How can I use the generic formatting ("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") in `PeriodFormatterBuilder`?

Comment: @BugsHappen Would that make sense? Wouldn’t it be too easy to confuse with a date and time? In any case I’m not a regular Joda-Time user, so I don’t know whether or how that’s possible. Did you check the documentation? Did you search? When you find out, maybe leave a helpful comment here.